# What is the best way to automate REST api

Tags: rest, api, selenium, automation, minitest

I am trying to automate REST api methods. I wanted to know which will be good way to automate using `java+Selenium+httpClient` or using `ruby+minitest`.

**Please Help...**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using httpclient in java, better to use Jersey Clients[Jax-RS implementation]. The following links will help you to get familiarity with Jersey client.
https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/client.html

http://howtodoinjava.com/jersey/jersey-restful-client-examples/

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at this.
https://api-bot.com/
It builds API from a Schema file.